Images are not getting displayed on Vercel site but are visible in sitecore xmc pages editor
After publishing the item, images are NOT loading on the Vercel site. When I try to click on image link from the edge it gives following error -
ERROR 9404: Could not fetch the image — the server returned HTTP error 404 Not Found

Probably images are not getting published. How can I troubleshoot further because while publishing there is no error?
Thanks
Shrutika

What do the urls of the images look like?

@Shrutika I am not aware if your issue is same as this one. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/37476/error-404-loading-images-published-to-experience-edge-using-image-sizing-param -- If yes, you can check out the following link as well if it matches your case and raise a support ticket if required - https://developers.sitecore.com/changelog/xm-cloud/1.5.91-base-image-update%3a-resolved-issues
